# Eclipse Indigo Update from SR1 to SR2

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-indigo

How can I update Eclipse to the newest service release SR2?

I have selected *http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo* as my only update site. At some point during the update I get the following error.

[image]

Comment: Any reason you just do not unzip a new download?

Comment: I'm not sure if I overwrite any settings I made to Eclipse. There are so many config files. I don't understand why the update isn't working. It worked for the update to SR1 as well.

Comment: You can select indigo but make sure it can contact other update sites.  You might have hit an timeout issue, does it give the same problem now?

Comment: I have selected Mylyn and Webtools update sites as well now but I'm still getting an error. I don't think it's a timeout problem. Why is it so hard to make all dependecies available on the offical Indigo update site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't change anything but it is working now. Looks like someone has finally added all missing dependencies on the update servers.

Comment: Nothing :) Make sure you have only selected the indigo update site. It worked then.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to just download the new eclipse package. Deleted my old eclipse installation directory and unzipped the new archive to the same location. Then I just had to set my workspace directory again and finally I had to install all plugins I previously had installed.

Only small problem was to get the proper version (x86 or x64) because I could not check which Version I had previously installed. So I 1st got x64-eclipse but on that one I couldn't got subclipse to work. The x86-version worked like a charm.

Dunno why x64-subclipse didn't worked because my suite runs on windows-x64 with a x64 jdk but I don't care for the moment because I just write x86 programs atm anyway.